# modify admin auth backend

Tags: python, django, django-admin

By default, after authentication on /admin, function `authenticate()` returns `User` object,
 what if i want to get proxy model for the User (i.g. called HandyUser) in return ? In my project, in all custom auth backends, i'm using HandyUser instead of User. 
thanks

Comment: Write a middleware `process_request` to replace `request.user` with your HandyUser instance?

Answer (score 0):

According to the django docs http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-user, you need to add to your settings file:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app.HandyUser'
```

And then when you reference your User class, call the `user.get_profile` method which will return the instance of HandyUser.